# How to prepare list which contains list objects?

Tags: java

I am fetching the records from database and those value like this

```
1,"a"
1,"b"
2,"c"
3,"d"
3,"e"
4,"f"
```

Here I got result into ResultSet now I want to prepare list like

```
[[a,b],[c],[d.e],[f]]
```

Any one can help me how to solve this, I tried with the list and map concept but I am getting last list object only.
Thanks

Comment: Please post what you have so far.

Comment: I need to group the values as a list of list objects, by using this list obj I will generate jsp page using <c:forEach> loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a Map, but use an `Integer` as the key, and a `List<String>` as the value. Simply perform a check for each key encountered that the map contains a list (empty or otherwise). If it doesn't then *first* add the list, then append the value to the list.

You could also investigate [MultiMaps](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: Since the first column is apparently a contiguous series of numbers, you don't *need* to use a map for this, you can do it with a list of lists. It may be useful to use a map, though.

Comment: I tried with this but the key should be repeated that why existing value override and am getting one value which contains like [[1,b],[2,c],[3,e],[4,f]]